# What fragment specifiers (metavariable types) should be used in macro-by-example for a module path + type name?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm finding myself write code like this:

```rust
// Of course I could add a use statement, but there's still undesireable duplication.
// in the real code theres anywhere from 3 to 10 items in the tuple,
// but that would just clog up this example
pub fn cols() -> (crate::foo::bar::A, crate::foo::bar::B) {
    (crate::foo::bar::A, crate::foo::bar::B)
}
```

Many times over. I tried to create a macro to spit out this function for me:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_cols {
    ( $namespace:path, $($col_name:ty,)*) => {
        pub fn cols() -> ( $( $namespace::$col_name, )* ) {
            ( $( $namespace::$col_name, )* )
        }
    }
}
```

but no matter what fragment specifier I pick for the metavariables (`path`,`ident`,`ty`,`tt`, combinations thereof) it errors. What's the magic incantation to get this to work?

The types `A` and `B` look something like this:

```rust
// In "foo.rs"

pub mod bar {
    pub struct A;
    pub struct B;
}
```

[An (erroring) example on the rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e637ced9ecd6283f472872aaf95e1594).

---

There is of course an XY problem here: I'm using the [diesel](https://diesel.rs/) crate and have structs with `Queryable` derive impl on them, and I want to be able to `.select()` the correct columns to fill a given struct. While there probably are other solutions, I still want to understand why the macro I wrote doesn't work, and what would work if anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with tt-munching:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_cols {
    (@build-tuple
        ( $($types:path,)* )
        ( $($ns:ident)::* )
        ( $col_name:ident, $($rest:tt)* )
    ) => {
        impl_cols! { @build-tuple
            (
                $($types,)* 
                $($ns::)* $col_name,
            )
            ( $($ns)::* )
            ( $($rest)* )
        }
    };
    // Empty case
    (@build-tuple
        ( $($types:path,)* )
        ( $($ns:ident)::* )
        ( )
    ) => {
        ( $($types,)* )
    };
    (
        $($ns:ident)::*,
        $($col_name:ident,)*
    ) => {
        pub fn cols() -> impl_cols! { @build-tuple
            ( )
            ( $($ns)::* )
            ( $($col_name,)* )
        } {
            impl_cols! { @build-tuple
                ( )
                ( $($ns)::* )
                ( $($col_name,)* )
            }
        }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=638eab18685d9b42693f9d2a105d24cf).

**Edit:**

The reason why simple matching doesn't work is that you cannot concatenate paths in Rust macro (without the help of a procedural macro). This is because, quoting the reference (https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#transcribing):

> When forwarding a matched fragment to another macro-by-example, matchers in the second macro will see an opaque AST of the fragment type. The second macro can't use literal tokens to match the fragments in the matcher, only a fragment specifier of the same type. The ident, lifetime, and tt fragment types are an exception, and can be matched by literal tokens.

This is true not only when forwarding to another macro, but also when forwarding to the compiler.

You want to build two different AST fragments: a [`Type`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#type-expressions) for the return type (each type in the tuple), and an [`Expression`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html) for the body. That is, `crate::foo::bar::A` (for instance) fulfill two roles: in the return type it is a type (specifically [`TypePath`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/paths.html#paths-in-types)), and in the body it is an expression (specifically [`PathExpression`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/path-expr.html)).

If we look at the definition of both (`TypePath` and `PathExpression`), we see they're essentially equal to the following (ignoring irrelevant parts like generics and function paths):

*Path* :
  `::`<sup>?</sup> *PathIdentSegment* (`::` *PathIdentSegment*)<sup>*</sup>

*PathIdentSegment* :
  [IDENTIFIER](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/identifiers.html) | `super` | `self` | `Self` | `crate` | `$crate`

If you are not familiar with EBNF notation, this means a list of identifiers (`:ident` in `macro_rules!`), separated by `::`s.

So, when you're doing something like:

```rust
macro_rules! concat_ns {
    ($ns:path, $type:ident) => {
        fn my_fn() -> $ns :: $type { todo!() }
    };
}
concat_ns!(crate::foo::bar, A)
```

Your macro invocation builds an AST similar to:

```
MacroInvocation
  ...
    Path
      PathIdentSegment `crate`
      PathIdentSegment `foo`
      PathIdentSegment `bar`
    COMMA
    IDENTIFIER `A`
```

Your macro wants to build an AST similar to:

```
Function
  ...
  FunctionReturnType
    Type
      Path
        <Insert metavariable $ns here>
        <Insert metavariable $type here>
```

Which gives you:

```
Function
  ...
  FunctionReturnType
    Type
      Path
        Path
          PathIdentSegment `crate`
          PathIdentSegment `foo`
          PathIdentSegment `bar`
        PathIdentSegment `A`
```

But this is an invalid AST, since `Path` can contain only `PathIdentSegment` and not other `Path`s! (Note: this is not the exact process, but it is more-or-less the same).

Now you also understand why the tt-munching solution works: there, we never create a `Path` node, and just keep the raw identifiers. We *can* concatenate raw identifiers and create a single `Path` from them (this is generally the reason tt-munchers are used: when we need to not use Rust macro's syntax fragment capturing abilites because we want to restore them after).

Comment: Do you know why the `path` token type doesn't work?

Comment: @Shelvacu Added a explanation.